# How to convert Python Dataframe utc time column to epoch timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a df with time column in ISO Format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2021-05-01T16:08:59.094953+00:00','2021-05-01T16:08:56.675183+00:00','2021-05-01T16:08:56.675183+00:00']})
```

[image]

How can i convert this time column to epoch timestamp in Python?

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY this approach

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time).astype(int) / 10**9
```

Comment: what is the logic for performing / 10**9 ?

Comment: @spidermarn `.astype(int)` gives you nanoseconds since the epoch; so you divide by 10**9 to get seconds.

Comment: @spidermarn, converting time to int gives the nano secs elapsed since 1970-01-01 (epoch) and dividing by 10*9 (10*3 x 10*3 for nano and mili secs)